Can't dupe hammer question because I added a tag, but I could have done it _before_ the edit

Convert raw string (having escape characters) to unicode/utf8 string
Convert "\x" escaped string into readable string in python

When voting to close 1) as duplicate of 2), the system didn't allow dupe hammering because I have added the python tag myself. However, I removed the python-3.x when adding the python tag. I have gold badges for both python and python-3.x, so could have closed it before the edit regardless.
In hindsight I could have closed first and then edited. But perhaps the system could detect this case and not block the closure?

This is definitely not a bug. It's [tag:status-bydesign]. The system is doing exactly what it's designed to do. The only tag the question has in which you have a gold badge is one you added to the question yourself. You are not permitted to use your gold-tag-badge hammer when you are the one that added the tag in which you have the gold badge.

That you also removed a tag in which you have a gold tag badge isn't something the system looks at. You could create a [tag:feature-request] to request the logic to look at that be added. I don't, personally, think it's worth the developer effort, as I expect that it's a quite rare circumstance and is something that can easily be worked around by just voting to close prior to making the tag edit. I could be convinced, not that you need to convince me, if it's something that happens quite often.

It may be by design, but that's bugged-by-design. You shouldn't lose privilege by doing something in a slightly different order, just like you shouldn't be able to escalate privilege by doing something in a slightly different order. There is already evidently a query which checks what tags you added in the edit, so the change to the query to consider what tags you removed sounds pretty trivial.

EITHER things are allowed and you go on some kind of watch list for people who did something that might be for dodgy reasons, OR it should be blocked like it is (but potentially there is a bug here if the reverse order might still be allowed). But the situation that you describe where you are free to do things which are easily exploited without any kind of auditing, that would be very unwise. You may have only good intent (and even people with good intent can go into an automation mode where they do all the wrong things for all the right reasons), you cannot speak for all your peers.

"I removed the python-3.x ..." - So why should you be able to use a duphammer in the python-3.x tag, which by your opinion doesn't belong to the question? It is like using a duphammer in the c++ tag for a Java question, which initially was mistagged. Well, you are able to use such duphammer before the retagging, but that usage is definitely not intended.

To further highlight the point @Tsyvarev mentions, if instead of Python 3.x it was another tag maybe the Numpy tag (You have a gold badge on it) but it was not relevant to the question, would you still say you should be able to dupe hammer the post?

@tsyvarev The point is that if you have both cpp and java gold tag, then the “abuse” that this restriction is trying to protect against (i.e. retagging just so that you can close) obviously does not apply here. So yes I think someone with both cpp and java should be able to hammer  that, we should trust our users are doing good with their edits and not harm here.

@wim: You probably want to suggest an approach, when a retagging could be treated as trusted for an editor, if the editor has a gold badge in a tag (T1) belonging to the question at the moment when the retag begins. And If a particular trusted retagging produces new tag (T2), where the editor has a gold badge, then they will be able to duphammer the question. That way tag T2 is treated as if it initially exists, or as if has been added by other user. Well, such model has a sense. But if you want to suggest it, you need to create a feature-request question, as you told by the mod.

@Tsyvarev such a query might be challenging to implement because it depends on order of events. How important is it that you had the tag badge when you made the edit vs the point of closing. Do we really need to protect against someone swapping T1 for T2, earning a tag badge in T1, and then dupehammering it?
